# htaccass subdomain redirecting problem with subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In root .htaccess I have this command to redirect any subdomain to subfolder - for example john.anypage.com to anypage.com/subdom/john/

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI,L]
```

This works well, but I don't want to server leave direct access also to that subfolder from browser - https://www.anypage.com/subdom/john/
It create mess and doubles in google page search.

What I tried with rewrite in root or subdomain folder makes no action or unfinite cycle.

```
RewriteRule ^/subdom/john/(.*)$  https://john.anypage.com/ [R=301,L]
```

So I want to have permanent subdomain john.anypage.com redirect withnout possibility enter subfolder /subdom/john/ directly.

Comment: `RewriteRule` checks on the current, internal path. You need a `RewriteCond` that checks the original Request URI for this. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/39764374/10955263 for an example.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can find the right answer there...